# Alternative of `route -n` of Linux in Mac

Tags: network

How can I see the list of routes and its corresponding gateway in a Mac ? The command in linux is `route -n` .

For a particular IP address, I am able to get the routes for an particular IP address via `route get 10.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not at a Mac to play with terminal, but is `netstat -rn` what you need?